# how to handle RxAndroid errors in the main thread

Tags: error-handling, rx-java, rx-android

I'm new to rxJava/Android and surprised that my `onError` lambda is  sometimes called on the main-thread and sometimes not, although I use `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`

*Example 1*: `onError` on main-thread
this works as expected: `onError` is called on the main-thread

```java
Observable.error(new RuntimeException("RTE"))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(s -> {
                Log.e(TAG, "onNext("+s+")-thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            },
            throwable -> {
                Log.e(TAG, "onError()-thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            });
```

log-output:

```
onError()-thread: main
```

*Example 2*: `onError` **NOT** on main-thread

```java
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
        subscriber.onNext("one and only");
    }
})
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.timeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.subscribe(s -> {
        Log.e(TAG, "onNext("+s+")-thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    },
    throwable -> {
        Log.e(TAG, "onError()-thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    });
```

the output is something like this:

```
onNext(one and only)-thread: main
onError()-thread: RxComputationScheduler-4
```

I thought that after calling [observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#observeOn(rx.Schedul), ALL emissions should be done on the main-thread.

so I have these questions:

1. I could not find any documentation that specifies under what circumstances `onError` is called in which thread. Anyone knows a link?
2. I do of course want to display some error-indication in the GUI: so how can I force `onError` to be ALWAYS called in the main-thread?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just found out that I only need to change the order of calls. When I call `observeOn` after `timeout` it works as expected:

```
.timeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

log-output

```
onNext(one and only)-thread: main
onError()-thread: main
```

The reason is, that `observeOn` will only affect everything below the call, and only until some other operator changes the thread again. In the example above, `timeout()` will change to the computation thread.

Note, that `subscribeOn` works differently. It does not matter where in the chain you call it.
You should only call it once (when you call it multiple times the first call wins: see *"Multiple subscribeOn"* in this [Blog](https://upday.github.io/blog/subscribe_on/))

Here is a nice blog-post with more details: [RxJava- Understanding observeOn() and subscribeOn()](http://tomstechnicalblog.blogspot.co.at/2016/02/rxjava-understanding-observeon-and.html)

Answer (score 5):

Because [`.timeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timeout.html) by default operates on `Schedulers.computation()`.

Comment: but [observeOn()](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/observeon.html) should override that default, right?

Comment: .timeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, [DesiredScheduler])