# Can't toast on a thread that has not called, RxJava2

Tags: java, android, android-toast

I have this code:

```
compositeDisposable.add(RetrofitClient
            .getApi()
            .getData()
            .flatMap(response -> {
                Data data;
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    data = response.body();
                    //insert data to database
                    Database.getInstance(context)
                            .getDao()
                            .insert(data);                     
                } else {
                    ResponseBody responseBody = response.errorBody();
                    if (responseBody != null) {
                        data = new Gson().fromJson(responseBody.charStream(), Data.class);
                    }
                }
                return Observable.just(data);
            })
            .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {
            //get data from database                   
                Data data = Database.getInstance(context).getDao().getData();
                return Observable.just(data);
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .retryWhen(throwableObservable ->
                    throwableObservable.take(1).delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            .doOnTerminate(view::hideScreenLoader)
            .subscribe(this::showData, throwable -> {
                Toast.makeText(context,
            throwable.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }));
```

I can't understand why sometimes users got this error: "Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException Can't toast on a thread that has not called Looper.prepare()".

Toast must called at main thread, thanks.

Comment: Toast is a ui element and you need to call it from applications main thread.

Comment: I know it, but what is wrong, i can't understand, i have: ".observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())", that says, that result will be work at main thread

Comment: your throwable might be operating on separate therad. use `System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());` to chech on which theread it is working.

Comment: @KaranMer, oh, it says: "RxComputationThreadPool-1"

Comment: try using new Observer() with subscribe and you can monitor for error

Comment: possible, i decided this problem, i found this topic -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39835978/how-to-handle-rxandroid-errors-in-the-main-thread, i must swipe "retryWhen" and observeOn, because "retryWhen" has delay func, that switch to computation thread :)

Comment: Try it, good luck with that...

Answer (score 2):

I found the decision in this topic: [how to handle RxAndroid errors in the main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39835978/how-to-handle-rxandroid-errors-in-the-main-thread);

Need to swap "retryWhen" and "observeOn", because retryWhen has "delay function", that switch to computation thread :)